# As I am using jQuery mobile?

Tags: android, input, numeric, android-optionsmenu

I have designed a web app and it has a form which has one field below like,

```
phone:<input type="text">
```

When I touch this screen (selecting the textbox to enter the data), the qwerty keypad is enabled by default. It is with character after pressing shift I can enter numbers in the text field.

ex:

```
<select name="source" data-native-menu="true">
```

and

```
<select name="source">
```

The above example shows a lot of variation while selecting the options in Android mobile which I observed.

Comment: hmmmm -  language barrier doesn't help obviously - not entirely sure what you're asking..?

Comment: I am waiting for the review of the editing. Next time, use the code block (the {} button) to mark the code, because half of the post was not visible to anyone.

Answer (score 0):

In the meantime, I am going to guess. Do you want to restrict the input to numbers? Does this help you?:

```
<input type="number" min="0" max="10">
```

(you can choose whatever min and max values you want or use only `input="number"`)
That should force android to open the numeric keyboard instead of the full qwerty upon gaining focus.